# WPF 3D Animation Rotation a Object seperat to the X Axis and Y Axis at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, rotation

Seeking a solution all axes separately to animate all with an object. It must also work simultaneously. Unfortunately, I have found after long search anything yet.
My sample code does not work because I have to give all axes.
When I try it with Vector3D (0,1, -1), he always takes the shortest path, which I do not want to. Even with two animations it does not work as it always performs the final animation.

I hope you understand my problem. It would be nice if you can help me out.

```js
 RotateTransform3D rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D();
            RotateTransform3D rotateTransform2 = new RotateTransform3D();
            Transform3DGroup  transGroup = new Transform3DGroup();


            transGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
            transGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform2);


           // 3D Objects
            wire_2.Transform = transGroup;
            wire_235235235.Transform = transGroup;
            wire_3.Transform = transGroup;
            wire_4.Transform = transGroup;



            // Set Center
            rotateTransform.CenterZ = 2.33;
            rotateTransform2.CenterZ = 2.33;

            // Axis rotation Selection
            AxisAngleRotation3D rotateAxis = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0,1 ,0 ) , 180);
            AxisAngleRotation3D rotateAxis2 = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, -1), 180);        


            Rotation3DAnimation rotateAnimation = new Rotation3DAnimation(rotateAxis, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));          

            Rotation3DAnimation rotateAnimation2 = new Rotation3DAnimation(rotateAxis2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            rotateAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            rotateAnimation.IsCumulative = true;

            rotateAnimation2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            rotateAnimation2.IsCumulative = true;

            // Animation
            rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation2);
            rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in your source:
*Look at the bottom -> the  `rotateTransform.BeginAnimation`  should be `rotateTransform2.BeginAnimation`*

```
RotateTransform3D rotateTransform = new RotateTransform3D();
RotateTransform3D rotateTransform2 = new RotateTransform3D();
Transform3DGroup  transGroup = new Transform3DGroup();


transGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
transGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform2);


// 3D Objects
wire_2.Transform = transGroup;
wire_235235235.Transform = transGroup;
wire_3.Transform = transGroup;
wire_4.Transform = transGroup;



// Set Center
rotateTransform.CenterZ = 2.33;
rotateTransform2.CenterZ = 2.33;

// Axis rotation Selection
AxisAngleRotation3D rotateAxis = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0,1 ,0 ) , 180);
AxisAngleRotation3D rotateAxis2 = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, -1), 180);        


Rotation3DAnimation rotateAnimation = new Rotation3DAnimation(rotateAxis, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));          

Rotation3DAnimation rotateAnimation2 = new Rotation3DAnimation(rotateAxis2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

rotateAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
rotateAnimation.IsCumulative = true;

rotateAnimation2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
rotateAnimation2.IsCumulative = true;

// Animation
//  !HERE!
rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation2);

// it should be:  rotateTransform2.BeginAnimation.....              
rotateTransform2.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation2);
//  ^^^^^^^

rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

Happy coding...

Comment: I'm unfortunately. You're right. Sometimes one sees hardly louder trees of the forest.

Comment: A fresh look from fellow coders, works great. Good luck.

Comment: It's possible to change the rotation speed during the rotation is running. I have tried to change it with den rotateAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Drehzahltime/2);  rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform3D.RotationProperty, rotateAnimation);  -  but it reset the rotation position back, befor.

Comment: You'll have to start a new animation. It will stop the previous animation (as you already noticed :S  )

Comment: It´s possible change the rotation speed without stop the rotation

Comment: You might try altering the `Duration` property of the Rotation3DAnimation instance. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.duration(v=vs.110).aspx